# PHPExcel: Add col from 1 xls to a different xls based on common cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

PHP 5.3 and using PHPExcel Library 1.7.8

I would like to  do a phpexcel version of vlookup. I have two xls files in 1 dir that have been uploaded through php.

dir/fileA.xls
dir/fileB.xls

I need to bring in one value per row based on a joining of fileA col1 values.

**I Have**

fileA.xls

```
===========================
emp_no.   fname     lname  
===========================
1     Sam       Smith
5     Lea       Crosby
7     Harlan    Myers
---------------------------
```

fileB.xls

```
===========================
test_number emp_no.   score  
===========================
1           1         98
16          5         64
14          7         76

---------------------------
```

**I Need**

to create a new fileC.xls OR rewrite fileA.xls (append new 'score COl?)

```
===========================
emp_no.   fname     lname    newCol_score 
===========================
1        Sam       Smith      98
5        Lea       Crosby     64
7        Harlan    Myers      76
---------------------------
```

Seems so simple yet Ive been googling for 3 hours and nothing. Found one similar post but the guy wanted the new data in a separate worksheet. I need 'score' brought in in the same worksheet either as new file  or just appended to fileA.xls. Only 1 worksheet with all the data.

thanks for any help or links to help....

Answer (score 0):

Load both workbooks fileA.xls and fileB.xls into different PHPExcel objects $objPHPExcelA and $objPHPExcelB.
Then you can use the addExternalSheet() method to copy a worksheet from $objPHPExcelB as a new sheet in $objPHPExcelA

```
$objPHPExcelA->addExternalSheet($objPHPExcelB->getActiveSheet());
```

then you can use an actual VLOOKUP() formula in your new column.

The alternative is to load both workbooks as above, loop through the rows in $objPHPExcelA reading the emp_no column; then loop through the emp_no column row by row in $objPHPExcelB until a match is found, and then read the value from the score column in that row of $objPHPExcelB to store in the new column in $objPHPExcelA; repeating until all employees have been updated.